# Change Size of UIImagePickerView displayed as Popover in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, uiimagepickercontroller

I am creating an app for iPad Pro. It will only be used in Landscape mode. This get photos for imageView the app, I use the UIImagePickerController.

**Abou the `UIImagePickerController`:**

I've been studying the Docs of UIImagePickerController and one fact important is:

From [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIImagePickerController):

> **The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only**. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified, with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional information or manage the interactions between the camera interface and your code.

The solution I've found to show `UIImagePickerController` in landscape mode is displayed as Popover.

**What I have:**

THIS IS A PROJECT EXAMPLE

My Storyboard:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUckK.png

- 1 NavigationBar with 1 Bar Button
- 1 Image View

**My Swift Code:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .Landscape
    }

    @IBOutlet var itemBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    @IBAction func getImageButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        let image = UIImagePickerController()
        image.delegate = self
        image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        image.view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleHeight, .FlexibleWidth]
        image.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover

        image.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = sender

        self.presentViewController(image, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

        let theInfo: NSDictionary = info as NSDictionary

        let img: UIImage = theInfo.objectForKey(UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage) as! UIImage

        imageView.image = img

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

**My question is:**

Knowing that I can not show UIImagePickerController in landscape, I can change the size of UIImagePickerController displayed in Popover?

If the answer is yes, how can I do this?

I tried to use the image.view.frame but do not get change.